# How to pass a React component state to a TypeScript namespace?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

Assuming I have a namespace that counts from 0-10

```
namespace Counter{
    export function count(){
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
             //doSomething
        }
    };
}
export default Counter;
```

I have another React component with a counter variable in its state

```
state = {
    counter:0
}
```

How can I update the state of this React component using the `count` function of `Counter` namespace